# Group Concat using sparql query

Tags: sparql

Can some one help me how to use group_concat in sparql query. When i am using in the database it is pulling out iri from the data. How to pull the the labels for the objects present in the database using group_concat.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will usually have IRIs with a label. Now, to return labels only, a query like this will work:

```
SELECT ?item ?label
WHERE {
 ?item rdfs:label ?label
}
```

Note that `rdfs:label` is conventionally used for labels, but any name can be used - it depends on the data that you have.

Now, imagine we want to find a `GROUP_CONCAT` of children's names, grouped by mother.
First, the query for the children and labels looks like this:

```
SELECT ?mother ?child ?label
WHERE {
 ?mother :hasChild ?child .
 ?child rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

Notice that `?mother` and `?child` will be bound to IRIs here, and `?label` to a string.

Now for the `GROUP_CONCAT`, you will just need a query like:

```
SELECT ?mother (GROUP_CONCAT(?label; SEPARATOR=", ") AS ?concat)
WHERE {
 ?mother :hasChild ?child .
 ?child rdfs:label ?label .
}
GROUP BY ?mother
```